# Image Link to Email not working

Tags: html, image, email

I'm having trouble getting my image link to work when someone presses the picture button, and I'm not sure why.  It works on my phone and my computer, but it doesn't work on other people's computer for some reason.  Please let me know what I need to do to get this fixed.

Thank you.

```
<div class="logo2">
  <a href="mailto:careers@remaxfutura.com?Subject=Career%20information%20Request;" target="_top">
<img src="http://www.remaxfutura.com/admin/web/files/1469815489_Request_an_Appointment.png" style="display:inline-block;" /> </a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note, you have an extra `</div>` in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be like this, you don't need to set target while adding link to mailto, the code should be like this

```
<div class="logo2">    
<a href="mailto:careers@remaxfutura.com?Subject=Career%20information%20Request;>
<img src="http://www.remaxfutura.com/admin/web/files/1469815489_Request_an_Appointment.png" style="display:inline-block;" />
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it wasn't working before I added the target attribute either.

Answer (score 1):

The markup of your code is worng. May be it's the problem.

```
<div class="logo2">
  <a href="mailto:careers@remaxfutura.com?Subject=Career%20information%20Request;" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://www.remaxfutura.com/admin/web/files/1469815489_Request_an_Appointment.png" style="display:inline-block;" /> 
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: which part? No need to be rude. Just let me know what I did wrong.  Sorry for not being a genius and notice evry single piece of syntax like the rest of the coding community.  Your comment doesn't even let me know what's wrong with the code, so I doubt you know either